# How should I think about this feedback circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, stability, frequency-response

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKZkT8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am analyzing the noise gain of this circuit to determine the frequency response of this amplifier. The noise gain is 1 + ZF/Z where ZF is impedance between the inverting input and the output.

One way I think about the noise gain is that it is the inverse of the voltage at the inverting input if the op amp output is 1V e.g.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8s7tu.png)</sup>

I can't wrap my head around how to think about the noise gain in this circuit. If I think about the current flowing from the output to the inverting input I get a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5cUys.png)</sup>

But if I think about the current flowing from the inverting input to the output I get a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdG09Q.png)</sup>

In one case I get a smaller capacitor, in the other I get a zero in the noise gain. LTSpice simulations show both. How do I think about this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C1, r2 and R3 form a t-network. It is a way to create large resistance from small value resistors. Plenty of documents on how to analyze it.

If you are looking to amplify small current , t network is the wrong approach to take to minimize noise. Use a large value resistor instead. Look up old keithley manuals to see how they did it.

Comment: I made a mistake analyzing the circuit that was revealed after reading this: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa068b/slaa068b.pdf.